# How can I use an API result in all my class?

Tags: javascript, api, class

I created a `JS` class `MapController` with one method which call an `API` `JC Decaux`. In a success case this method `initJcDecaux()` create different markers on a google map. But I would assign a result of `$ajax()`to my public property `this.data`. I tried this code but it's not good... If someone can help me ? Thank you.

```
class MapController {
  constructor(mapIdPosition) {
    this.mapIdPosition = mapIdPosition;
    this.position = {lat: 43.6009272, lng: 1.4452841};
    this.zoom = 14;
    this.markers = [];
    this.data = [];
  }

  initMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapIdPosition), {
      center: this.position,
      zoom: 5,
    })
    this.map.setZoom(this.zoom);
  }

  initJcDecaux() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Toulouse&apiKey=6d8e030000000000000000000000000000',
      type: 'GET',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.data = data;
        data.forEach(this.addMarkerOnMap.bind(this));
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.markers,
            {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
      }.bind(this)

    })
  }

  addMarkerOnMap(data) {
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.position,
      map: this.map,
      title: '',
    })
    this.markers.push(this.marker);
  }
};

const map1 = new MapController('map');
map1.initMap();
map1.initJcDecaux();
console.log(map1.data);
```

Comment: well if you get initJcDecaux() to return the Promise object generated by $.ajax, then any code which calls that function could attach its own event handler to get the result of the AJAX cal and use the data. So literally `initJcDecaux() {
return  $.ajax({`...etc. Then a caller could write something like `map1.initJcDecaux().then(function(data) { //now do something with data.... });`

Comment: Or, if you just want the ajax to be called once, and then be able to re-use the data, you could assign the result data to a public property of your class, and then other code could access that property to get the data.

Comment: I edited my post, and I have add a public property and I'm trying to assign a result data to my public property but... I don't know why, something is wrong.

Comment: it would help if we could see the wider class definition, including where you declare the class, and where you declare the property. The current example is incomplete. P.S. What do you mean "something is wrong" exactly? What happens when you try to access the property? What result do you get?

Comment: Oh I forgot as well...probably the main reason it isn't working is because AJAX functions are **asynchronous**. `console.log(map1.data);` is happening **before** the "success" function runs to actually populate your data. Some simple debugging would demonstrate that fact to you. I was assuming you would realise this, and would avoid writing any code which would try to access the data instantly, and would instead wait until it had been populated.

Comment: Yes, I had think about this and tried to do `setInterval(function() {console.log(map1.data)}, 5000);` but I've the same result `undefined`.

Comment: setting an interval or timeout is not reliable. You cannot guarantee how long the AJAX request will take in reality. The only way to _guarantee_ the data is available is to use a callback, or use the async/await pattern. Assuming it _did_ happen to take less than 5 seconds to complete and still showed nothing, then you have a separate issue which we'll need to debug.

Comment: Reducing this to a minimal example of just this problem code, in actual fact there doesn't seem to be an issue, even using the dodgy timer method, the request usually completes in time and populates the data. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0mn3dwv4/. Or we could make it more reliable using Promises as I mentioned: https://jsfiddle.net/0mn3dwv4/1/

Comment: P.S. It probably wasn't a great idea to give us your API key :-). They're not strictly secret, but you probably don't want it being shared around for everyone to use up your allowance (if they set such limits on that API)

Comment: Ok great, I understand my mistake, thank you very much !